# Assign foreach IEnumerable<string> to Object.StringId using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to do below in linq

```
 foreach (var ar in allResults)
                    trans.Add(new Tran
                    {
                        TranId = ar
                    });
```

New to linq, Please help

Comment: What type is `trans`?

Comment: trans is List<Tran>(); 

Tran{ string TransId }

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing seems to be transforming each element of `allResults` to a `Tran`, and adding all of them to `trans`.

"transforming each element to another object" corresponds to a `Select` operation in LINQ, and adding all the transformed elements can be done with the `AddRange` method:

```
trans.AddRange(allResults.Select(ar => new Tran { TranId = ar }));
```

If `trans` is always initially empty, you could use `ToList` and directly assign to `trans` instead:

```
trans = allResults.Select(ar => new Tran { TranId = ar }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using AddRange.

```
trans.AddRange(allResults.Select(ar => new Tran{ TranId = ar})))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather use ForEach

```
allResults.ToList().ForEach(t => trans.Add(new Tran() {TranId = t}));
```

Look at this answer posted in MSDN [LINQ equivalent foreach](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e459a5f8-4027-4a1a-8f01-87799222a3e8/linq-equivalent-of-foreach?forum=csharpgeneral)

The **ForEach** takes an Action and you cannot return anything from an Action.

Comment: This isn't LINQ, and doesn't do the same thing as OP's code. Not to mention that this also ends up with two lists, not one (although one is discarded).